# Is there anyway to not allow a pygame window to be resizable?

Tags: pygame

I'm wondering if there is a way to stop people from being able to resize a pygame window and if so how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not a pygame window is resizable is determined by the "flags" that are passed to it via the `pygame.display.set_mode` function. Multple flags can be set separated by | operators. Simply do not pass the `pygame.RESIZABLE` flag and the window should not be resizable!

```
import pygame
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = 800
    height = 600
    title = "Non-Resizable Window"
    pygame.init()
    size = (width, height)
    #pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE)#resizable
    pygame.display.set_mode(size)#not resizable
    pygame.display.set_caption(title)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
                pygame.quit()
```